# Typescript get property decoration for class object

Tags: typescript, decorator

I have class with property decoration

```
class User {

  @key
  id : number;

  @maxlength(50)
  Name: string;
}

let user = new User();

for(property in user) {
  // how to get the Property decorations!!!!
  // for example id has @key decoration
}
```

I want to get all decoration for every property.

Thanks.

Comment: can you add the implementations for ```key``` and ```maxlength```

Answer (score 0):

An annotation has no representation at runtime. It just executes when the class is being initialized, and then it's gone.

In order to persist information about the annotations, you could attach your own metadata to the class instance like this:

```
const annotationsKey = Symbol();

function initAnnotationMetadata(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
  target[annotationsKey] || (target[annotationsKey] = {});
  target[annotationsKey][propertyKey] || (target[annotationsKey][propertyKey] = []);
}

function addAnnotationMetadata(target: any, propertyKey: string, annotation: Function) {
  target[annotationsKey] = { ...target[annotationsKey], [propertyKey]: [...target[annotationsKey][propertyKey], annotation] };
}

function key(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
  initAnnotationMetadata(target, propertyKey);
  addAnnotationMetadata(target, propertyKey, key);
  // Your annotation logic...
}

function maxlength(max: number) {
  return function(target: any, propertyKey: string) {
    initAnnotationMetadata(target, propertyKey);
    addAnnotationMetadata(target, propertyKey, maxlength);
    // Your annotation logic...
  };
}

class User{

  @key
  @maxlength(50)
  id : number;

  @maxlength(50)
  name: string;

  [annotationsKey]: { [key: string]: Function[] };

  constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

let user = new User(2, 'Jose');

for(const property in user)
{
  console.log(`Annotations of property ${property}: ${user[annotationsKey][property].map(x => x.name).join(', ')}`);
}
```

Comment: I run the code and get this error : Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'unique symbol' can't be used to index type 'User'.
  Property '[annotationsKey]' does not exist on type 'User'.ts(7053)

Comment: There is to declare the `annotationsKey` in the class to avoid this error. Please take a look at my edit

Comment: Thank you work fine, What the main differences between your solution and the reflect-metadata package?

Comment: My solution attaches the metadata directly on the object which means that you only need the `annotationsKey` to retrieve it. The `reflect-metadata` package illustrates a proposal to the JavaScript language and it is implemented with an internal `metadataMap` inside the library itself. My solution adds a somewhat hidden property (as the key is a `Symbol`) but you still could retrieve it with `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`. With `reflect-metadata` the only way to retrieve the metadata is to use `Reflect.getMetadata` from the library itself.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Can you explain how to use your code with class decoration , like:

@className("post")
export class Post {}